# VoiceOver controls are selectable when hidden

Tags: ios, voiceover

I have a UIView which contains some controls (e.g. buttons, labels, etc).  I overlay this view onto another view (using addSubview).  If the user has VoiceOver on, he can swipe left and right to select the controls.  However if I hide the view so the controls are no longer visible, the user is still able to swipe and select them (although they don't actually work).  Since this is very confusing to a blind user, I would like to keep this from happening.  I have even tried removing the view that contains the controls (using removeFromSuperview) but the user can STILL swipe to select them (although the little boxes which highlights them are no longer in the correct positions).  It is like VoiceOver has memorized that those controls were once there and will remember that forever more.

I also found the property 'accessibilityElementsHidden' and I have tried setting that to YES on the view which contains the controls when it is hidden, but that does not seem to work either.

Is this a bug in VoiceOver, or am I missing something?  Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the opposite problem! If my overlay view (containing the buttons) is transparent (alpha=0.0) then none of its subviews (buttons etc.) are found by VoiceOver. My case, I'd like to have those controls accessible (via VoiceOver) even when the overlay is hidden - but I can't!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "memorized" part makes me think you aren't doing something like `UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil)` after removing the subviews.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was missing.  Thank you very much!  By the way I asked this very same question over on the Apple Development forum and received no responses.  I always seem to find more knowledgable people on stackoverflow.

Comment: I try to answer stuff there too, just a matter of chance. BTW, if you can require iOS 5, you can have VoiceOver-modal views, which can make life a *LOT* easier.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I did see that, but I want to be able to support the Gen 2/3 iPod which appears to have 4.2 as the max version that you can install (I suppose I could always check for the OS version and make or not make the iOS 5 calls accordingly).

Comment: I use modality on iOS 5, and do the best I can on 4.x.

Comment: thanks for those tips David! I assumed setting the boolean should ensure Voiceover knows that the layout did change. wonder why it's made to not work (according to my assumption)

Comment: @DavidDunham, can you please clarify something for me? In my case, I do not add subviews or remove them. Rather, I animate the alpha of my container UIView (containing some buttons) from 0.0 to 1.0 and vice versa. This means that my view hierarchy never actually changes. Still VoiceOver doesn't "see" my buttons when they're invisible (in my case - I want it find them, even after they faded out). Have you any idea about the connection between alpha transparency and accessibility?

Comment: @MottiShneor don’t really know, as I typically hide items after I fade them. Presumably the basic idea is that VoiceOver users are interacting with the same basic UI, and since you can’t tap alpha 0 elements, they’re excluded from VoiceOver.

I suppose you could reposition them under something visually opaque, or perhaps override an accessibilityChildren in a parent.

It’s also possible alpha 0.01 would allow interaction but not visibility?

Or move them so only 1 pixel is still on screen?

Answer (score 8):

The documentation for "accessibilityElementsHidden" states:

> A Boolean value indicating whether the accessibility elements
>   contained within this accessibility element are hidden. ..... The
>   default value for this property is NO. You might use this property to
>   hide views that are covered by the arrival of a new view. In this
>   case, the hidden views might remain visible onscreen, but they are not
>   the focus of the user’s actions.
>
> You might also use this property to hide a transient view that
>   VoiceOver users don’t need to notice. For example, VoiceOver doesn’t
>   need to describe the translucent view that appears when users adjust
>   the volume on their devices, because the aural feedback of this action
>   is sufficient.

So based on this, in order to have those subviews ignored by VoiceOver, you'd actually want to set this to "YES" on the parent view.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had mistyped before and I was setting it to YES.  The problem appears to be that I was not calling UIAccessibilityPostNotification after I removed the windows.